# How do I completely uninstall mySQL on XP, including the root password?

Tags: windows-xp, mysql

All I need is to be able to log in using root, but have forgotten the password. None of the steps to reset i found online work (i don't even have some of the executables mentioned such as mysql-nt.exe)

However I have no problem deleting all databases (i have scripts) and intallations and starting completely from scratch... but uninstalling and deleting directories doesn't work.

Thanks.

---

mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking

just gives me an error.. service won't start. For that matter the service won't start at all due to some unknown error (1067) even after I remove and reinstall... I think the only answer now is to buy a new laptop.

Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to reset the root password, then do the following:

Stop the MySQL service.

go to the command prompt in your mysql bin folder run the following command

```
mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

(skip-networking to stop remote connections.)

then use mysql command line tool and run the following script:

```
USE mysql;
UPDATE user set Password = PASSWORD('new-password') where User = 'root';
```

then stop the service by running

```
mysqld stop
```

restart the mysql service and login with your new password.

Comment: How is he going to start the MySQL command line tool if he forgot the root password?

Answer (score 0):

Open up windows services manager (start > run > services.msc > OK). Locate the MySQL service and note down its path (right click > properties > Path to executable). Once you note down the path, stop the service.

Now assuming that the path is `C:\mysql\bin\mysqld` run the command `C:\mysql\bin\mysqld --remove`. You can then remove the directories.